# what encoder can take advantage of 16-core setup? converting/ripping Blu-ray to mp4 format

Tags: mp4, conversion, bluray

I'm thinking of upgrading my 6-core setup (single CPU) setup to a 2x8-core/CPU setup. I'm wondering what software will allow me to fully utilize all the cores.

I've been using handbrake but I do not think it utilizes all the cores. I prefer software that is freeware but paid software is ok too if it's not to expensive.

Thanks!

Comment: FYI: Handbrake is ffmpeg with a gui. I find ffmpeg (unhindered by third party stuff) is pretty amazing.

Comment: Adding on to @DigiVisionMedia's comment: I fully agree and use both Handbrake and ffmpeg via command line very often. They take advantage of multiple CPUs, multiple cores, and hyperthreading very efficiently. My setup is 2x 6-cores and it flies.